# Codeigniter sort by price pagination not working from page 2 onwards

Tags: codeigniter, sorting, pagination

I'm facing some issue with CI pagination. The sorting are all good now but when I try to navigate to page 2 onwards, the sorting of the listing will then be "restarted". Restarted I mean, to go back to the first sorting method when I first load the page.

Sort options: Most recent, price low to high & price high to low

Page Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $query_string = $this->input->server('QUERY_STRING');
    $page_start = $this->input->get('page');
    $products = $this->Marketplace_model->get_products($query_string);
    $data['products'] = array_slice($products, $page_start, 12);

    $this->_doPagination($data['products'][0]["total_rows"], $test);

    $data['sorts'] = array("recent" => "Most Recent", "lowtohigh" => "Price Low To High", "hightolow" => "Price High To Low");
    $data['sortselected'] = get_sortby();

    $data['selectedSortBy'] = $query_string;

    $this->template->set('title', 'Marketplace');
    $this->template->load('default_layout', 'contents', 'index', $data);
}
```

Pagination controller:

```
private function _doPagination($total_rows = NULL) {
    $per_page = get_perpage();

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['total_rows'] = ($total_rows != NULL) ? $total_rows : 0;
    $config['per_page'] = ($per_page != NULL) ? $per_page : 12;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['base_url'] = '';
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = '«';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_url'] = '?page=1&';
    $config['last_link'] = "»";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = false;
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = false;
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_products($query_string) {

    if ($query_string == 'recent') {
        $sql = "select total_rows=(select count(*) from o2o_pit_live_product)
            ,   * from o2o_pit_live_product order by supplier_on DESC";
    } elseif ($query_string == 'lowtohigh') {
        $sql = "select total_rows=(select count(*) from o2o_pit_live_product)
            ,   * from o2o_pit_live_product order by regular_price ASC";
    } elseif ($query_string == 'hightolow') {
        $sql = "select total_rows=(select count(*) from o2o_pit_live_product)
            ,   * from o2o_pit_live_product order by regular_price DESC";
    } else {
        $sql = "select total_rows=(select count(*) from o2o_pit_live_product)
            ,   * from o2o_pit_live_product";
    }

     $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Views:

```
<select name="filter" class="custom-select filter" id="filter" onchange="location = this.value;">
<?php foreach ($sorts as $skey => $sname): ?>
    <option value="?<?php echo $skey; ?>" 
    <?php
    if ($selectedSortBy === 'recent' && $skey === 'recent') {
    echo 'selected';
    }
    if ($selectedSortBy === 'lowtohigh' && $skey === 'lowtohigh') {
    echo 'selected';
    }
    if ($selectedSortBy === 'hightolow' && $skey === 'hightolow') {
    echo 'selected';
    }
    ?> >
    <?php echo $sname; ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

array_slice second parameter is set for from where records is start.you set page number instead of from where records start.so your code should be as per below

```
$start = ($page_start-1)*get_perpage();
array_slice($products,$start,get_perpage());
```

Comment: hi, its not working still. the result is in all order now.